# SQLi in phonegap fails on Create Table If Not Exists

Tags: javascript, database, cordova

So I've noticed a bug in my App (built with phonegap 2.6) recently and I've narrowed it down to the following SQL code at the start of the App from the usual populateDB():

```
tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tokens (token unique)');
```

It ***is*** being used correctly, from within "deviceready" event and all that, that's not it. The problem is - this will fail **the first time it is run** - it will be fine on all subsequent runs, like it's working as intended. However it's not acceptable for it to fail.
Here's the error I get on that first run:

```
code: 5
message: "could not prepare statement (1 no such table: tokens)"
```

This isn't a syntax error or anything like that, I don't know what it is. Has anyone ran into problems like that? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but sure you sure it's that exact line failing, and not some other query that is triggered before the table is created?

Comment: Not a silly question, I've considered it myself, but I don't think that's the case, as all the queries are executed further down the line (from a dbSuccess callback) - which doesn't happen if the query fails (hence the problem). It wouldn't explain why it would work on subsequent runs either.

Comment: Well, it would explain it if the table was actually successfully created the first time. Then a query triggered before the creation would already have an existing table to query.

Comment: Well that's what seems to be happening, the question is why does it fail the first time? Since it effectively means when user first runs the app it will fail - which is a sign of a shit App. Then again, that's Phonegap for you.